# Referencing a null value after delete

Tags: apex, trigger

I am a newbie in apex and I need to reference the opportunityId so that when the opportunity is deleted, the field in the Products opportunity will become NULL. See the photo below for my error.

```
 trigger UpdateLeaseForShow on Opportunity (After update, Before delete) {

Opportunity[] NotWonOpps = new Opportunity[0];
    for(Opportunity record:(trigger.isDelete ? trigger.old : trigger.new)) {
        if(record.StageName != 'closed won') {
            NotWonOpps.add(record);
        }
     }
        if(NotWonOpps.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
   Product2[] productdel = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN : trigger.old)]; 
   Product2[] products = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :NotWonOpps)];

   for(Product2 product: products) {
     product.Available_for_Lease__c = true;
     product.IsActive = true;
     product.RecordTypeId = '01261000000EDF9'; 
   }
     for (Product2 product: productdel){
     product.Available_for_Lease__c = true;
     product.IsActive = true;
     product.RecordTypeId = '01261000000EDF9';
       } 

   if(products.isEmpty()){
       return;
    }
    update products;
       }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing after modifications suggested by Boris?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

1) Change the trigger to be `before delete` rather than `after delete`. The latter executes after the record is physically deleted, so you want to catch it just before it gets deleted.

2) Inside your trigger, whether it's before or after delete, you need to use `trigger.old` to reference the records that are about to get (or got) deleted. When you have the same trigger running on delete and insert or update at the same time, you can so something like this:

```
for (Opportunity record : (trigger.isDelete ? trigger.old : trigger.new))
```

Comment: please check out my updated code.  Im not reallyfamilliar with trigger.old please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working code.. Thank you @Boris for the idea.. :)

```
trigger UpdateLeaseForShow on Opportunity ( After update, before delete) {

public List<Product2> products = new List<Product2>();
Set<ID> set_id = new Set<ID>();

for(Opportunity oppo : Trigger.old) {
    set_id.add(oppo.id);
}

if(Trigger.IsUpdate) {
Opportunity[] NotWonOpps = new Opportunity[0];
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.StageName != 'closed won') {
            NotWonOpps.add(record);
        }
    }
        if(NotWonOpps.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

   products = [SELECT Id FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :NotWonOpps)];
   //system.assertequals(products + 'hyhhtest','test');
   for(Product2 product: products) {
     product.Available_for_Lease__c = true;
     product.IsActive = true;
     product.RecordTypeId = '01261000000EDF9'; 
   }

   if(products.isEmpty()){
       return;
    }
    update products;
   } 

if(Trigger.IsDelete) {

    List<Product2> toDelete = new List<Product2>();
    products = [SELECT Id, Current_Tenant__c FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN (SELECT Product2Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :set_id)];

    for(Product2 produ : products) {
        if(produ.Current_Tenant__c != null) {
            produ.Current_Tenant__c = null;
            toDelete.add(produ);
        }

    update toDelete;
    }

}
}
```